# How to Mock an object with protected init

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to Mock an amazon services object to perform UnitTesting on a related code. I have done it as follows but each time the init is hit it crashes with error failed:

> caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "`- init` is not a valid
>   initializer

Normally the same object will be created using there factory method, so it seems the initializer is made private or something. How can such object be mocked ?

```
 class MyAWSiOTDataManager : AWSIoTDataManager {
    override func publishString(_ string: String, onTopic topic: String, qoS qos: AWSIoTMQTTQoS) -> Bool {
          print("publish string called")
          return true
    }
    override init() {

    }
 }

 let manager = MyAWSiOTDataManager()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call the designated initializer of `AWSIoTDataManager` inside your `init` call and remove the `override` decorator. That is why you got the error.

You can not mock something by subclassing it. With Swift, mocks are usually provided through a shared protocol. Define a protocol for the interface that you use from the third party library. Create an empty extension on the library with your protocol (there should be no code needed). Then implement a mock object against the protocol for use in your tests.